# How to do tunneling between proxmox server , which is clustered and having different public IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, virtual-machine, tunneling, proxmox

Question: How can I configure communication between specific nodes in a Proxmox cluster consisting of three servers with distinct IP ranges, hosted on Hetzner Cloud, to access a database created on Server 1 from Server 3? I want to restrict access to only two out of ten users on Server 3, keeping in mind that all three servers are in different subnets and have separate public IP addresses. Is changing the IP addresses of the clients a viable solution, and if not, what would be the recommended approach to achieve this?

Explanation: I have a Proxmox server cluster with three servers, each with its own IP range and hosted on Hetzner Cloud. I need to establish communication between specific nodes on Server 3 to access a database hosted on Server 1. However, I want to restrict this access to only two out of ten users on Server 3. It's essential to note that the servers are in different subnets, and each has a separate public IP address due to external hosting. I'm considering changing the client's IP addresses but would like guidance on the best approach to achieve this goal.

An IP routing detail of how to routing/tunneling between 2 nodes of different servers.